# Change gitlab markdown mermaid diagram size

Tags: gitlab, markdown, mermaid

Is there a way to set the size of diagram (i.e. flow chart) created with mermaid in Gitlab markdown? The default is just too large!

My markdown:

```
graph TD;
A[User click payment] --> B(Load Payment Gateway) --> C[User pay] --> D(Redirect to site)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Gitlab on gitlab.com, then the problem is being caused by your PC. I typed your markdown on my gitlab.com repo, and my diagram appeared just fine (See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwWtb.png)).

Try using a different browser or clearing the browser's cache

If you are using Gitlab on a hosted server, report this to your system administrator. Perhaps he needs to update the version of Gitlab currently installed.